# Where is the kernel source in build?

Tags: yocto

I build a yocto OS image, the image is done, but I can't find the kernel source.

I want to modify some files in the kernel source.

I see no any kernel source file in `build/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i built for Yocto dunfell , core-image-minimal image for qemuarm machine

You can find kernel source in

**build/tmp/work-shared/qemuarm/kernel-source**